# Have different Vaishnavite teachers made remarks on the relative merits of different Vaishnavite Puranas?

Tags: puranas, vaishnavism, bhagavata-purana, sects, vishnu-purana

Obviously Gaudiyas would rank the Bhagavatam first for its statement "Krishnastu Bhagavan swayam".

Ramanuja gave great importance to Vishnu Purana, but apparently never cited the Bhagavatam.

Do the teachers from different sects explain their ranking of the Vaishnavite Puranas?

note:  this is obvioulsy not an opinion-based question.  An example of what I am asking for is Ramanuja's supreme praise of Vishnu Purana in relation to other Puranas.

Comment: Sri vaishnavas say the Vishnu purana is the foremost of the puranas because it is shuddha sattva and has no tamasic or rajasic gunas. Some other vaishnava scholars  like Vedanta Desikan say the varaha purana is also another shuddha sattva purana.

Comment: i don't know about that.  Bhagavatam likens itself to the Ganga among rivers - and varaha purana provides clinching "satvika" refutation of the theory that only vishnu is called Narayana.

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32652/which-book-do-vaishnavas-give-more-importance-of-the-two-vishnu-purana-and-srima/32656#32656